# BigQuery tabledata:list output into a bigquery table

Tags: list, google-bigquery

I know there is a way to place the results of a query into a table; there is a way to copy a whole table into another table; and there is a way to list a table piecemeal (tabledata:list using startIndex, maxResults and pageToken).

However, what I want to do is go over an existing table with tabledata:list and output the results piecemeal into other tables. I want to use this as an efficient way to shard a table.

I cannot find a reference to such a functionality, or any workaround to it for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Important to realize: [Tabledata.List API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list)  is not part of BQL ([BigQuery SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference)) but rather [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/) that you can use in [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries) of your choice.
That said, the logic you outlined in your question can be implemented in many ways, below is an example (high level steps):

Calling `Tabledata.List` within the loop using `pageToken` for next iteration or for exiting loop.
In each iteration, process response from Tabledata.List, extract actual data and insert into destination table using [streaming data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) with [Tabledata.InsertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll) API. You can also have inner loop to go thru rows extracted in given iteration and define which one to go to which table/shard. 
This is very generic logic and particular implementation depends on client you use.
Hope this helps

Comment: That means the data is downloaded locally (outside BQ) and then sent back to BQ. I know how to do that and I don't need to use InsertAll (which is pretty expensive) but can use a simple insert job. The question is, can I do it within BQ without going back out again? Maybe with federated tables using google cloud?

Answer (score 0):

For what you describe, I'd suggest you use the batch version of Cloud Dataflow:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/

Dataflow already supports BigQuery tables as sources and sinks, and will keep all data within Google's network. This approach also scales to arbitrarily large tables.

TableData.list-ing your entire table might work fine for small tables, but network overhead aside, it is definitely not recommended for anything of moderate size.

Comment: Thanks Sean. So if I understand correctly: a) we have to go outside BQ to do this efficiently. b) Dataflow is essentially a way to use the Cloud Storage and the Compute Engine (so in theory one could programmatically call these two instead of using Dataflow). Correct? Now, does Dataflow have a Restful API, or do we have to use Java to work on it? That would overly complicate things...

Comment: For what you're describing, cloud dataflow does seem to be the most efficient means. They provide the glue and orchestration logic to process BigQuery table in parallel, and write the results to one or more output tables. You definitely could do it yourself directly by interacting with GCE, GCS, and BigQuery, but I think you'll find it pretty complicated. W.r.t. dataflow's API, since it's running your java code, you do need to interact with the java API for the parallel processing aspects. However, I believe there are restful management APIs to trigger execution etc.